# Appending an array field, from another field, in MongoDB documents (with MongoClient) in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, dbmigrate

I have a collection called Users.

Here is an example of a doc.

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"},
"userId":"ANKIT",
"token":"token123",
"badge":{"$numberInt":"0"},
"useLocalCurrency":true,
"notifyCustomerRejected":true,
"notifyReworkRequest":true,
"notifyMoaApproved":true,
"notifyCustomerAccepted":true,
"__v":{"$numberInt":"0"},
"tokens":[]}
```

I am trying to push the `token` into the `tokens` array for all the docs in a DB migration.

This is what I have tried :

```
export function up(next) {
    let mClient = null;
    return MongoClient.connect(url)
        .then(client => {
            mClient = client;
            return client.db('notifications');
        })
        .then(db => {
            const User = db.collection('users');
            return User.find().forEach(result => {
                let { _id, userId, tokens, token } = result;
                tokens.push(token);
                tokens = Array.from(new Set(tokens));
                result.tokens = tokens;
                console.log(result._id);
                console.log(result.tokens);
                User.update({ _id: _id, userId: userId }, { $set: { tokens: tokens } });
            });
        })
        .then(() => {
            mClient.close();
            return next();
        })
        .catch(err => next(err));
}
```

By doing this I am only getting the 1st document updated the way I want and not the rest. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The call to `update` only modifies the first matched document.  You would need to use `updateMany` or pass the `multi` option to affect them all.

This code seems to be finding all documents in the User collection via collscan, and then running a separate update in a forEach loop:

```
            return User.find().forEach(result => {
                let { _id, userId, tokens, token } = result;
                tokens.push(token);
                tokens = Array.from(new Set(tokens));
                result.tokens = tokens;
                console.log(result._id);
                console.log(result.tokens);
                User.update({ _id: _id, userId: userId }, { $set: { tokens: tokens } });
            });
```

If you want to append the token to the array for every user try using:

```
            return User.updateMany({},{$push: {tokens: token}})
```

Comment: I tried using the `multi` option set to true, it still updates just the first document.
The `token` that is appended to the `tokens` array is different for all documents, so how do you suggest I use `updateMany` .